# How to provide options to script blocks?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to learn about script blocks at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-6.

I want to send a script block to an event registration with a command-line option to the registration command, like this:

```
$Block = {
Param($option)
Write-Host "The option was $option"
if ($option==ABC) {
    Write-Host "ABC was specified"
}
}
```

But when I test this by appending

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $Block -option ABC
```

I get the error

> Invoke-Command : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'option'.

Comment: Please do not move the target. `Register-ObjectEvent` is vastly different from `Invoke-Command`. The former cmdlet does not allow passing arguments to the scriptblock. Probably b/c passing arguments wouldn't make any sense in the first place. I've rolled back your last edit, b/c it invalidated the answers that had already been given. Please post a new question instead.

Comment: Ansgar, My followup question is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56994482/how-to-provide-options-to-event-registration . Something that you didn't tell me is that a new question must be worded differently from an older version of the question.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-3.0):

> **`-ArgumentList`**
>
> Supplies the values of local variables in the command. The variables in the command are replaced by these values before the command is run on the remote computer. Enter the values in a comma-separated list. Values are associated with variables in the order that they are listed. The alias for ArgumentList is "Args".
>
> The values in ArgumentList can be actual values, such as "1024", or they can be references to local variables, such as "$max".
>
> To use local variables in a command, use the following command format:
>
> ```
> {param($<name1>[, $<name2>]...) <command-with-local-variables>} -ArgumentList <value> -or- <local-variable>
> ```
>
> The "param" keyword lists the local variables that are used in the command. The ArgumentList parameter supplies the values of the variables, in the order that they are listed.

The first element from the `-ArgumentList` array becomes the value of the first named parameter in the scriptblock, the second array element becomes the value of the second named parameter, and so on.

Basically, your statement should look like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $Block -ArgumentList 'ABC'
```

Also, the syntax of the comparison operation in your scriptblock is wrong. The equality comparison operator in PowerShell is `-eq`, not `==`.

Comment: I appreciate the answer and yes I did read the documentation, but unfortunately I did not understand either your answer or the documentation. Powershell seems very different from other languages and shells that I have used and it will take me time to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you can always check the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6

```
$Block = {Param($option)
Write-Host "The option was $option"
if ($option -eq "ABC") // -eq instead of ==, string in quotations
   {Write-Host "ABC was specified"}
}

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $Block -ArgumentList "ABC"
```

If there are more arguments you can list them in order. Using script blocks isn't something you want to do very often. It's better to create a function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-6)

Comment: I have revised the question, following your answer. Please review as I'm still getting error messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the call operator on scriptblocks too, and just provide the arguments after a space or -option:

```
& $block abc

The option was abc
ABC was specified
```

And you can later assign the scriptblock to a function.  That's what a function *is*.

```
$function:myfunc = $block
```