# How to provide options to event registration?

Tags: powershell

I don't understand why the following code generates error messages. Powershell seems difficult to learn.

```
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher ...

$Action = {Param($option)
if ($option -eq "Copy")
   {Write-Host "Copy was specified"}
}

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action $Action
Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Changed -SourceIdentifier FileChanged -Action $Action -ArgumentList Copy
```

(This is an updated version of question [How to provide options to script blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56971047/powershell-how-to-provide-options-to-script-blocks))

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent?view=powershell-3.0). The `Register-ObjectEvent` cmdlet does not have a parameter `-ArgumentList`, so getting an error when trying to call the cmdlet with a parameter that it doesn't have is hardly surprising. And as I already told you in my comment to your previous question, passing arguments to an event action the way you're trying to do does not make much sense in the first place.

If your actions are so similar that defining different action script blocks would yield too much boilerplate you can easily discriminate by event inside the scriptblock, since that information is passed to the action automatically (via the variable `$Event`).

```
$Action = {
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $type = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType

    switch ($type) {
        'Created' { Write-Host "file ${file} was created" }
        'Changed' { Write-Host "file ${file} was changed" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That looks like what I was aiming for. I wanted to be able to copy files that change to a mirror folder. Now all I have to do is figure out how to use timing to delay copying changed files more often than a fixed minimum time granularity. Thanks for your help, and you don't have to be snarky about reading documentation. I've been an engineer for 40 years and have no trouble with documentation. My trouble is with having the time to make sense of Microsoft-style documentation given the other things that are important in my life.